# Using start command for multiple parameters

Tags: php, command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

programA have parameters to first call

```
"programA.exe id.dll id.exe -SERVICE -MODE 2"
```

and I want use sandboxie command line call programA

```
"C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" /box:sandboxname programA.exe
```

last I use php call by exec function

```
exec("start "C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" /box:sandboxname programA.exe id.dll id.exe -SERVICE -MODE 2");
```

It can not work. Please help me to correct.

Comment: Start with getting your quotes right ". Your command in exec() is a parse error.